# php - for with 3 values

Tags: php

i have:

```
@ = 1
# = 0,5
% = 0

max = 10
```

for example if i have: **3** then should show me:

```
@@@$$$$$$$
```

if i have **3,5** :

```
@@@#$$$$$$
```

etc

if i have 3,99 then = 3,5
if i have 3,49 then = 3,0

etc

how can i use this with foreach or for?

for whole number i can make:

```
$number = 8;
$one = 10 - $number;
$three = 0 + $number;
```

and

```
for($i=1;$i <= $one){
  echo "@";
}

for($i=1;$i <= $three){
  echo "$";
}
```

but how is the best solution if $number = 3,57

Comment: Sense. This question makes none.

Comment: I have no idea. Where do the `$`s come from in your first examples? What are you going to do with the `%`? Could you find better names for your variables, because `$one = 10 - $number;` makes no sense at all, and `$tree = 0 + $number;` looks even stranger.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this seems to be an attempt at generating ASCII representations of a [sign-value numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-value_notation) in which @ is 1, # is 5, and the string is padded out to `max = 10` characters with $.  Beyond that, though, I'm still lost.

Comment: Also, in the last code snippet, you need to add "`; $i++`" to the end of the `for`.

Comment: Sense none - Did you have a pub lunch?

Comment: is this some sort of homework ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood what you're after, this should do what you want:

```
<?php

function printItOut($number) {
    $s = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if ($i < $number%10) {
            $s .= '@';
        } else if ($i < ($number+0.5)%10) {
            $s .= '#';
        } else {
            $s .= '$';
        }
    }
    return $s;
}


echo printItOut(3.49), "\n";
echo printItOut(3.5), "\n";
echo printItOut(3.99), "\n";
echo printItOut(4), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
@@@$$$$$$$
@@@#$$$$$$
@@@#$$$$$$
@@@@$$$$$$
```

Inside the for loop, I using the modulus operator to find the integer remainder of dividing $number by 10.  So 3%10 gives a result of 3, 3.49%10 also results in 3.

In the first 'else if' block, I'm checking whether the number is 0.5 or more, since (3.49+0.5) is 3.99, and 3.99%10 is 3; but 3.5+0.5 is 4, and 4%10 is 4.